# Need to zero a formula field for group in Crystal Reports IX

Tags: crystal-reports

I am generating a margin percent in a report using CR IX.  The detail percentages work just fine but the subtotal by product code does not.  It always shows the same percentage regardless of the data that is pulled from the database.  The values I'm getting are these 32.87 and 67.13, no matter if the cost and margin are zero.
What I would like to do is in the group header zero out these two percentage fields.  I have the following in the suppress formula:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;{@SumMarginpct}= 0;{@SumTCpct}= 0;
```

but this has not worked.  The percent formula fields are the following:

```
Sum ({@total_cost}) / Sum ({@ext_disc_price}) * 100 ( for the SumTCpct field)
Sum ({@margin}) / Sum ({@ext_disc_price}) * 100     ( for the SumMarginpct field)
```

I am not a CR programmer, mostly sql and python so the nuisances of CR are not readily available :)

Appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks

@Craig
I have modified the formulas some based on reading a reference book and a web tutorial:

```
if Sum ({@total_cost}, {Rpt_MarginByProductCodeSp;1.product_code}) = 0
then 0
else
Sum ({@ext_disc_price}, {Rpt_MarginByProductCodeSp;1.product_code}) %
Sum ({@total_cost}, {Rpt_MarginByProductCodeSp;1.product_code})
```

this is one of the formulas, the other is just like to only it uses the Sum {@margin} field.

Comment: You don't need to 'reset' summarized fields; this happens automatically.

Comment: Please post the code that you use for each of the formulas that you are referencing in your question, if possible.

Comment: @Craig - I have added a new group footer and moved the percent field that I am calculating along with the product code that is giving me the group break.  The percent values are correct now. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Place these formula fields in the product-code group's footer:

```
// {@SumTCpct}
Sum ({@total_cost}, {table.product code}) / Sum ({@ext_disc_price}, {table.product code}) * 100

// {@SumMarginpct}
Sum ({@margin}, {table.product code}) / Sum ({@ext_disc_price}, {table.product code}) * 100
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Craig.

That is where the formula code is already. Created a percent formula field in the group footer and then added the formula to the field.

The problem is that on the first subtotal group which has a total cost price = 0 and a margin and extend discount price = 0, I get a percentage of 35.42% and 64.58% of 0. These percentages are the only group sub total percent that show up. Never uses the formulas to calculate the percentage, otherwise it would change.